# Restrict lenght of float python numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am dealing with numpy arrays and am running into an issue. It was giving a runtime-warning that I am trying to divide by zero. On further inspection I found this Error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Arush Mundada\Desktop\pyproj\ailib\main.py", line 36, in <module> model_rating.append(sum(abs((mai.calculate_model(input_array,models[x]))-answer_array))) File "C:\Users\Arush Mundada\Desktop\pyproj\ailib\myailib.py", line 102, in calculate_model output_arr = calculate_layer(input_arr2,layer,connectors) File "C:\Users\Arush Mundada\Desktop\pyproj\ailib\myailib.py", line 93, in calculate_layer output_arr[i] = node * (input_arr[con1]/input_arr[con2]) FloatingPointError: underflow encountered in scalar divide`

after further diggin I found that this was happening because it was attemting to divide 8.884313185203669e-161
1.5399031202408477e+160
these two numbers. I am guessing that numpy rounds them to zero, and hence the divide by zero. Is there a way to fix this, like by restricting the number of digits?

I was trying to perform division and multiplication between items of a numpy array.

Edit: My program slowly edits the numpy array by multiplying and dividing it. After 15 or so iterations it reaches such big/small numbers. Is there anyways I can prevent such big numbers?

This is the line that edits the values:

```py
output_arr[i] = node * (input_arr[con1]/input_arr[con2])
```

Is there a way of reducing the size? maybe cap it at some value?

Comment: Dividing something on the order of -161 (crazy small) by something on the order of 160 (crazy big) would result in something on the order of -320 (even crazier small). It is so small that it can't even be represented by a floating point value. This is what is referred to as "underflow": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow

Are you sure you need such small or big numbers? I would rethink your approach. Restricting the number of digits does not seem sensible to me

Comment: Your data might be corrupted and that's why you are getting such numbers. You should maybe check where are you getting this values from and correct them there before trying to do any operations with them. Are this numbers the result of a previous operation? Are you reading them from a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a limit, above or below which it is pre-defined